# How to append elements to a list with a loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

```
import random

count = 1
attack_count = 0
Node_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
a, b, c, d, e = 1,1,1,1,1
while True:
    value_list = random.sample(range(10, 100), 5) 
    a = value_list[0]
    b = value_list[1]
    c = value_list[2]
    d = value_list[3]
    e = value_list[4]

    print(count, "Round, Values : ", a, b, c, d, e)
    Biggest_N = max(a,b,c,d,e)
    index = value_list.index(Biggest_N) 
    print("Biggest Node:", Node_list[index]) 

    CH_list = []
    for i in range(count):
        CH_list.append(Node_list[index])
    print(CH_list)

    if count >= 10 :
        break
    count += 1
```

first, thanks for your help
I write this code by using Python.
In this code, I want CH_list to append element that Biggest Node each count.
for example, If Biggest Node is c in count 1, CH_list may print [c]
If Biggest Node is b in count 2, CH_list may print [c, b]
....

but it's not working, in my code,
If Biggest Node is b in count 2, CH_list print [b, b].

Can you tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I dont understand what the for loop is for at all, you only have one thing to append every while loop iteration

Comment: *it's not working* is not a proper way to describe the problem. Can you please provide the *exact* expected output: what should be in `CH_list` at the end of the execution?

Comment: When for example, `count = 5`, you add clear CH_List, and then add the *current* biggest index to the list 5 times.  So you always end up with identical elements on the list.  You need to set CH_List to [] outside of your loop, and then within your loop add one element to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random

count = 1
CH_list = []
attack_count = 0
Node_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
a, b, c, d, e = 1,1,1,1,1
while True:
    value_list = random.sample(range(10, 100), 5) 
    a = value_list[0]
    b = value_list[1]
    c = value_list[2]
    d = value_list[3]
    e = value_list[4]

    print(count, "Round, Values : ", a, b, c, d, e)
    Biggest_N = max(a,b,c,d,e)
    index = value_list.index(Biggest_N) 
    print("Biggest Node:", Node_list[index]) 

    

    CH_list.append(Node_list[index])
    print(CH_list)
    
    if count >= 10 :
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.
I don't speak English very well. And since it was my first time asking a question on this site, I was worried that my intentions would not be conveyed.
Nevertheless, kind people left their answers here. I feel saved.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is accumulate the biggest node for each iteration in a list, you have to declare `CH_list` outside the `while` loop. That way the list is not reset every iteration.

Also, there is no need for the `for` loop, since all it does is add the same node `count` times to an empty list.

Here is the solution:

```py
import random

count = 1
attack_count = 0
Node_list = ['a','b','c','d','e']
a, b, c, d, e = 1,1,1,1,1
CH_list = [] # Declare list outside loop
while True:
    value_list = random.sample(range(10, 100), 5) 
    a = value_list[0]
    b = value_list[1]
    c = value_list[2]
    d = value_list[3]
    e = value_list[4]

    print(count, "Round, Values : ", a, b, c, d, e)
    Biggest_N = max(a,b,c,d,e)
    index = value_list.index(Biggest_N) 
    print("Biggest Node:", Node_list[index]) 

    CH_list.append(Node_list[index]) # Append biggest node to the list
    print(CH_list)

    if count >= 10 :
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply.
I think my question must have been very rudimentary. But I couldn't solve it myself.
I will try to study further through your answer.